# MongoDB full text search matches partial words

Tags: mongodb

If I do a full text search for "Gray inv" with MongoDB (ver 3.2.6), I get a match on text containing "Gray investments".  This is with stemming turned OFF.  Why is this happening? I would have expected the search expression to only match complete words.

Query:

`db.clips.find( { "$text" : { "$search" : "\"Gray inv\"", "$language" : "none" } } )`

Index:

```
> db.clips.getIndexes()
[
        {
                "ns" : "mydb.clips",
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_id" : 1
                },
                "name" : "_id_"
        },
        {
                "ns" : "mydb.clips",
                "v" : 1,
                "key" : {
                        "_fts" : "text",
                        "_ftsx" : 1
                },
                "name" : "title_text_body_text",
                "default_language" : "none",
                "weights" : {
                        "body" : 5,
                        "title" : 10
                },
                "language_override" : "language",
                "textIndexVersion" : 3
        }
]
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We'll need some more information to provide context for your question. What version of MongoDB are you using? Can you also include the query and index statements?